# Selective numbering of equations with align

Tags: numbering, align

I have an `align` environment with 5 equations. I want 3 of them numbered, and the other 2 not numbered. I understand that there's other posts on the issue of selective numbering of those equations that are referred to in the body of the text, but that's different to what I'm trying to achieve.

I want the first three lines (equations) of the following to be numbered and the last two to be without numbering. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&R_{i,t} = \alpha_i  \\
&R_{i,t} = \beta_i  \\
&R_{i,t} = \gamma_i  \\
&\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{it}]=0;\textrm{   } \textrm{Var}[\epsilon_{it}]=\sigma^2_{\epsilon_{i}}\\
&i \in \{1,2,...,N\};\textrm{   } t \in \{1,2,...,T\}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add `\notag` to the lines you don't want numbered.

But if you are using `fleqn`, you don't need `align`, you can use `gather` instead (the `\notag` works the same) and remove the `&`s:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
R_{i,t} = \alpha_i \notag \\
R_{i,t} = \beta_i \notag \\
R_{i,t} = \gamma_i \notag \\
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{it}]=0;\textrm{   } \textrm{Var}[\epsilon_{it}]=\sigma^2_{\epsilon_{i}}\\
i \in \{1,2,...,N\};\textrm{   } t \in \{1,2,...,T\}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(You probably wanted the other lines numbered).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than choosing which rows to enumerate you could let `mathtools` enumerate only the equations you reference.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        a = b \\      
        b = c \label{eq:unused} \\      
        c = d \label{eq:used} % Only this row will be enumerated as it's the
                              % only row that is referenced to.
    \end{align}

    Here I will make a reference to the eq:used label \eqref{eq:used} 
    % Be sure to use \eqref and not \ref instead.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This answer was first given by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5701/n-n in a duplicated
question. I think this solution is very elegant and very useful. Why would you want to enumerate unused stuff?