# Choose which rows in multi-line equation to assign numbers to

Tags: equations, amsmath

If i do:

```
\begin{align}
    a = b \\
    b = c \\
    c = d \\
\end{align}
```

The output will be like:

```
(1)        a = b
(2)        b = c
(3)        c = d
```

If I use algin* instead. No row will be enumerated.

Is there a way to get the following output?

```
           a = b
           b = c
(1)        c = d
```

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/selective-numbering-of-equations-with-align and the linked questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than choosing which rows to enumerate you could let `mathtools` enumerate only the equations you reference.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a = b \\
  b = c \label{eq:unused} \\
  c = d \label{eq:used} % Only this row will be enumerated as it's the
                        % only row that is referenced to.
\end{align}
\eqref{eq:used}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Than you very much.

Comment: It didn't work as well as I expected.

All my \refs point to the first \subsubsection above them and no equation is being enumerated.

Comment: @htellez Did you try `eqref` rather than `ref`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much.