# flalign numbering

Tags: math-mode, numbering

I have an equation that is so large that it needs to span over several lines. However I also have a particular alignment that I want, so I used the flalign environment to lay it out as I want it to be. However, I end up with each line being numbered, when I only want one number for the whole equation:

```
    \begin{flalign} \label{soundness:goal}
    &   \gamma \tdash \{p\}\cmd\{q\} \implies \forall \sigma \in \TStore. \; \forall h \in \THeap. \; \forall \rho. \\
    &   \quad (\sigma, h) \vDash_{\rho} p \implies \forall t \in Trace_{\gamma}(\state{\cmd}{[\sigma]}{ h}). \; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}. \; length(t) < n
    \end{flalign}
```

Is there anyway that I can have an flalgn environment or similar, but only have the last line numbered?

Comment: Add `\nonumber` or `\notag` for the lines you want unnumbered.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, that worked perfectly! Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks! Already a member of other SX communities though, so I know the ropes :)

Comment: @JulianSutherland You're welcome. Answerd added.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [In the `align` environment, how to number only one of the lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67755/5764); [Selective numbering of equations with `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65207/5764)

Comment: How are the `\tdash`, `TStore`, and `\THeap` macros defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\nonumber` or `\notag` for the lines you want unnumbered. By the way, are you sure `flalign` is the best option? I ask because this environment is rarely used.