# Numbering specific lines in align environment

Tags: numbering, align

I want to number specific lines of an equation in the `align` environment. I've seen how to use `gather` instead of `align` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/selective-numbering-of-equations-with-align), but putting `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` in the preamble messes with the other equations in the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.20in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

For any test function $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$,
\begin{align}
\langle f'(t),\phi(t) \rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(t)\phi(t) \mathrm{d}t \\ 
&= [f(t)\phi(t)]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\phi'(t) \mathrm{d}t \\ \nonumber
&= -\langle f(t),\phi'(t) \rangle
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I want to number the first and third lines, *not* the first and second.

Comment: Your `\nonumber` should be *before* the ``\\`` that *ends* the second line.

Comment: Yay! Care to submit this as an answer below?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In each line of your `align` environment, `\\` *ends* the equation. So, any actions you want to perform on that particular line need to go *before* the ending `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

For any test function $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$,
\begin{align}
  \langle f'(t),\phi(t) \rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(t)\phi(t) \mathrm{d}t \\ 
    &= [f(t)\phi(t)]_{-\infty}^\infty 
         - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\phi'(t) \mathrm{d}t \nonumber \\ %%%%%%%%
    &= -\langle f(t),\phi'(t) \rangle
\end{align}

\end{document}
```